# How to seed data with elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to seed data into database but it's not working because I can't find a way to iterate over lists in paralel like in pseudocode below

```
for elem1, elem2, elem3 in list1, list2, list3 do
  Repo.insert{elem1, elem2, elem3}
end
```

Here is my data.

```
@list_of_names      ~w(Daniel Admin Goran Tomislav User1)
@list_of_usernames  ~w(daniel admin goran marex User2)
@list_of_passwords  ~w(123456 000000 123456 123456 123456)
```

and I need to insert it using User struct.

```
Repo.insert!(%User{
  name: name, 
  username: username, 
  password: password
})
```

I've tried using the [Phoenix docs](https://phoenixframework.readme.io/docs/seeding-data) but this code below doesn't work.

```
defmodule Rumbl.DatabaseSeeder do

  alias Rumbl.Repo
  alias Rumbl.User



  @list_of_names      ~w(Daniel Admin Goran Tomislav Marin)
  @list_of_usernames  ~w(daniel admin goran marex marin)
  @list_of_passwords  ~w(123456 000000 123456 123456 123456)

  def insert_user do
    Repo.insert!( %User{
      name:     (@list_of_names     |> Enum.take_random), 
      username: (@list_of_usernames |> Enum.take_random), 
      password: (@list_of_passwords |> Enum.take_random)
    })
  end
end
(1..5) |> Enum.each(fn _ -> Rumbl.DatabaseSeeder.insert_user end)
```

Error after:  `mix run priv\repo\seeds.exs`

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Enum.take_random/1 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * take_random/2

    (elixir) Enum.take_random(["Daniel", "Admin", "Goran", "Tomislav", "Marin"])
    priv/repo/seeds.exs:27: Rumbl.DatabaseSeeder.insert_user/0
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:657: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.each/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1628: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.reduce/3
    (elixir) lib/range.ex:92: Enumerable.Range.reduce/5
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1627: Enum.reduce/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:656: Enum.each/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:71: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:296: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

Comment: You don't need to use `<%= ... %>` in code. That is only if you are using eex. What are the errors you are actually getting? Also, what made you think you needed to use `<%= ... %>`?

Comment: What do you not understand about that error? You are trying to call a function that takes 2 arguments and you are only passing 1. [Look here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#take_random/2) for how to use the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Enum.zip/2` twice to zip 3 lists, and then use `for` iterate over them.

Assuming this code will be in an exs file like `priv/repo/seeds.exs`:

```
names = ~w(Daniel Admin Goran Tomislav User1)
usernames = ~w(daniel admin goran marex User2)
passwords = ~w(123456 000000 123456 123456 123456)

for {{name, username}, password} <- name |> Enum.zip(usernames) |> Enum.zip(passwords) do
  Repo.insert!(%User{
    name: name, 
    username: username, 
    password: password
  })
end
```

<sup>This would be clearer if Elixir had a `Enum.zip/3` function to zip 3 lists, but it doesn't.</sup>

Comment: i'll try it now and see if it runs

Comment: ahhh im hashing a pass before inserting

Comment: You probably want `Repo.insert!(User.changeset(%User{}, %{name: .., ...}))` then.